# Finding Palindrome Number with js but problem with negative numbers

Tags: javascript

```
/**
 * @param {number} x
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isPalindrome = function(x) {
    
  let a, b, c = 0;
    a = x%10;
    x=x-a;
    b= x/10;
    c= b%10;
    let d = b-c;
    let f = d/10;
    let g = (a*100) + (c*10) + f;
    if (g==x && x>0)
        return "true";
    else 
        return "false";
};
```

when the number is negative its not saying false, it says true instead. But i added x>0 condition. What's the problem? And btw my code also doesn't look good maybe it's not a good way to solve the palindrome problem.  And also i am not so sure if its working with numbers with more than 3 digits.

Comment: you subtract a negative (a) from x, bringing it above zero. eg: `-15 % 10 == -5`

Comment: You're modifying the value of x on line 3 of the function

Comment: If you're looking for another way to solve the problem itself, the simplest way is to convert the number to a string and just check if it's a palindrome the normal way

Comment: `return x == "".split.call(x, "").reverse().join("");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you want to use mathematical operations to get the answers as divisions and modules. You can use the following code that works for any number:

```
/**
* @param {number} x
 * @return {boolean}
 */
var isPalindrome = function (x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  const original = x;
  let pali = 0;
  while (x > 0) {
    pali = (x % 10) + pali * 10;
    x = Math.floor(x / 10);
  }
  return original === pali;
};
```

Also the conditional evaluation in your code is not in the correct place, the first thing that you need to do is evaluate if the number is a positive one, if the number is negative you don't have to do any processing because you know that the number is not a palindrome.